# Runtime-load A DLL In The Same Directory (Not The Application Directory)

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I have a situation where I need to load a DLL (libcocotb.dll) at runtime (using `LoadLibrary`) from another DLL (libembed.dll) that exists in the same directory. These DLLs are not in the same directory as the application.

```
> tree
.
├── ...
├── libcocotb.dll
└── libembed.dll
```

Specifying just the library name `LoadLibrary("libcocotb.dll")`, did not find the library. `LoadLibrary(".\\libcocotb.dll")`, did not find the library. Adding the directory to the `PATH` seems like the wrong answer, and I would need to determine the location of the directory at runtime since the binaries need to be relocatable (they are going in a Python wheel at the end of the day).

On Linux, I can just add `$ORIGIN` to the RPATH of the loading DLL. Is there nothing similar on Windows? I am not very familiar with Windows loader and library system.

Comment: Little bit difficult to understand why you don't want to use the full path to the dll. A simple solution.

Comment: I would have to compute the path to the dll. I don't know where it is until the application runs.

Comment: You don't need to know it before the application runs. This is your solution.

Comment: That's vague, could you elaborate?

Comment: What's vague? Use the full path to the dll.

Comment: See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) for details on how the OS searches for DLLs when using relative paths, and how you can influence that search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it in Windows is:

- save the `HMODULE` of `libembed.dll` when it gets loaded, which is passed as the first argument to its [`DllMain` entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain);
- later, when preparing to load the other DLL, use [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) with the saved `HMODULE` to get the full path to `libembed.dll`;
- split the `libembed.dll` filename off the full path, using for example the [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathremovefilespecw) API or the [`_splitpath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=msvc-160) CRT function;
- combine the resulting directory path with the `libcocotb.dll` filename to build the full path to the other DLL, using for example [`PathCombine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew) or [`_makepath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/makepath-wmakepath?view=msvc-160);
- use the full path to `libcocotb.dll` to `LoadLibrary` the DLL.

Comment: I tested and this does work. For a final implementation I decided against using `PathRemoveFileSpec` and `PathCombine` since I don't want to have to link to another windows library. Instead, I split the filename using C++ string functionality, and appended the other library name.

Comment: @ktb Those were just the "official" recommendations, and `shlwapi` is often linked already by other components or libraries. That said, it's certainly possible to do it by direct string manipulation.